# Проверка целостности файлов

Tags: java, png, проверка

Как проверить целостность изображения формата **png**?

Т.е., имеем несколько сотен файлов данного типа в папке. Необходимо прогнать их скриптом на целостность, проверить, что каждый из них корректно открывается и не битый или нечитабельный. Есть мысль организовать это через Java, т.к. начал изучение на курсах недавно, но не совсем уверен подойдет ли для данной задачи, либо что-то попроще посоветуете.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Конечно проще есть, вот например [pngcheck](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/apps/pngcheck.html) и никакой java не нужно.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! То что нужно, просто вызвать через батник и перелопатит всю папку на проверку!

Answer (score 8):

Так как вопрос на SO, то предполагаю необходимо техническое решение вопроса?

В png встроены чеки, каждый чанк хранить CRC32. Но, чтоб это всё проверить, надо прогнать весь файл целиком.

С другой стороны, обычно вполне достаточно проверить первые и последние байты.

Первые байты всегда: `{ 137, 80, 78, 71, 13, 10, 26, 10 }` ([дока](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Structure.html)).

В 16-ричной системе:

```
89 50 4e 47 0d 0a 1a 0a
.. P  N  G  ...........
```

Ну и последние байты должны быть в 16-ричной системе:

```
00 00 00 00 49 45 4e 44 ae 42 60 82
........... I  E  N  D  ...........
```

В Java что-то такое:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param bytes массив байт файла
 * @return
 */
public boolean isOk(byte[] bytes){
    if (bytes.length < 4) 
        return false;

    if (bytes[0] != 0x89 || bytes[1] != 0x50) 
        return false;
    if (bytes[bytes.length - 2] != 0x60 || 
        bytes[bytes.length - 1] != 0x82) 
        return false;

    return true;
}
```